# Config MYSQL BUT not applied

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have a problem in file mysql (etc/mysql/my.cnf). I change from "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1" to "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2"-> restart serive apache2. But not working, so i checked again in phpmyadmin by query "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit'" And result is 1. (I used server Ubuntu 16.04 Apache2 PHP7.0 Mysql 5.6.39). Thank so much.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you say you are editing my.cnf? Restart the mysql service not apache.

https://superuser.com/questions/282115/how-to-restart-mysql

Comment: The results remain unchanged . Thank for support